# Ubuntu Videos doesn't play my .mp4 videos

Tags: video, dependencies

I want to play my .mp4 videos using Ubuntu Videos (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos). This application suggests additional plug-ins in order to work. The plug-in that required to install are:

- MPEG-4 AAC decoder
- H.264 decoder

Unfortunately, after I clicked `Install` button, I got an error **Package dependencies cannot be resolved**. Detail of error message is provided below:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
  gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
                        Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Well, actually, I have played some .mp4 videos successfully using Ubuntu Videos when fresh Ubuntu was installed on my computer. This problem occurred when opening .mp4 videos after downloading additional libraries for `.flv`.

I have tried solutions that I found on internet. But, it came no luck.

Sorry for possible duplicate question.

Comment: What ? The title says .mp4 but later you say "This problem occurred when I was trying open .flv" Which on is it .mp4 or .flv or both ? Any way best way to get the 3rd party music / video codecs is to run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`, this may fix your playback issue.

Comment: I did the command above. Unfortunately,  I got the same error message.

*Sorry, I have edited my question for clear explanation.

Comment: Sorry please elaborate, did restricted-extras install ? Then even after installing that you still get `The following packages have...` ? You say `This problem occurred when opening .mp4 videos after downloading additional libraries for .flv` what libs did you download, you should remove them and restricted-extras should be all you need, if you give me the commands you used for the .flv libs I will show you how to uninstall them

Comment: Yes, I did. I have installed restricted-extras. I don't remember what libs I have downloaded. I don't know to remove them.

Comment: Open a terminal and keep pressing the up arrow on your keyboard, until you find the commands you entered for the .flv codecs and post them here

Comment: I didn't install them from terminal. But, the pop message that is produced by Ubuntu Videos (suggesting additional lib to install after open `.flv` file).

Comment: I did command `sudo apt-get install -f` and I got this below `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavcodec54:i386 libavutil52:i386 libgsm1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386
  libogg0:i386 libopencore-amrnb0:i386 libopencore-amrwb0:i386
  libopenjpeg2:i386 libopus0:i386 librtmp0:i386 libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386
  libspeex1:i386 libtheora0:i386 libva1:i386 libvo-aacenc0:i386
  libvo-amrwbenc0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx1:i386
  libx264-142:i386 libxvidcore4:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.`

Comment: Your error says, that the package versions are too high (libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed). Can you confirm weather or not other players work, easy way to do this is in terminal type `mplayer` then a space then drag a video on to terminal, press enter, did it work ?

Comment: It worked using `mplayer`. But, I don't know why playing `.mp4` video on Ubuntu Videos still got the same error message.

Comment: Well at least it seem to be a problem exclusively with that gnome video app and not a problem with your OS, First just try `sudo apt-get -f install` see if it can force a fix, if not I would remove `videos` and then reinstall it, like this `sudo apt-get purge videos` then install it back through `software center` and the `software center` should resolve any dependence issues as it installs, this should give you the latest version with plug ins, It is strange you are having this with a pre installed app, I can't seem to find any othe instances of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` with the following command, It may help:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I did the command above. Restarting my Ubuntu and then playing a .mp4 video. Unfortunately, I got the same error message.

Comment: @Shokatsuryō Mention the error message

Comment: The error message is same what I wrote in question above. **Package dependencies cannot be resolved...**

Comment: Use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`, hope works

Comment: @M.Fooladgar, Why would that work ?

Comment: aptitude may either install the plugin or give a better idea on why it won't install.

Comment: The restricted extras is installed fine, it is just Gnome video that won't work other players are working fine.

Comment: Thank you all for your amazing response. I decided to use other players instead, for example VLC player. But, this problem still exists for Gnome Video.